# Ejecutar una condicional donde sea distinto de block JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Lo que pasa es que no se me cumple la condición `if` 
¿Qué puedo corregir para que me funcione?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buscarHMn').click(function() {
    if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat')!= "none") {
      $('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css("display","block");
      $('#cont-campoBusq').animate({
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        opacity: 100,
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("ELSE");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.buscarHMn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cont-campoBusq-relat {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: slateblue;
  display: none; 
  float: right;
  
}

#cont-campoBusq {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: palevioletred;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buscarHMn">Click</div>

<div id="cont-campoBusq-relat">//Esto es asi; tenia el codigo mal
 <div id="cont-campoBusq" class="centFRH">CampoBusq</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Sí se ejecuta su sentencia IF.

Comment: pero no aplica el estilo que esta dentro del if

Comment: Porque este codigo no se ejecuta ???, $('#cont-campoBusq').animate({
        background: purple,
        opacity: 100,
      }, 1000);

Comment: Revisar mi respuesta , en primer lugar **el valor de la propiedad background debe ir entre comillas** , luego en nombre de la propiedad es `backgroundColor`  para Jquery-UI

Comment: Perfecto me funciona, ahora me falta asignarle un calback; luego que se ejecute la animación querré que empiece otra animacion , mañana lo hare por ejemplo algo así

Comment: $('#cont-campoBusq').animate({
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        opacity: 100,
      }, 1000,función(){ alerta("hola")}); espero que este en lo correcto y el código sea correcto sino corrijanme porfa

Comment: Verificar nuevamente mi actualización de mi respuesta, si tiene dudas comentar ahí , debajo de ella . si resolvió sus dudas e inconvenientes por favor marcarla. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar si ingresa al bloque del `IF`

> ¿Por qué no muestra la animación de cambio de color ?

Porque [Jquery/Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) especifica claramente que no todas las propiedades pueden ser animadas haciendo solo uso de [Jquery/Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/),se requiere un plugin extra como [Jquery-Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) , o [Jquery-UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)

**No olvidar que los valores para las propiedades van entre comillas (simples o dobles)**

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$('#cajita').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({
   color: 'red',
      backgroundColor : '#fff'
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
#cajita{
background:yellow;
width:40px;
height:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <div id="cajita" >Click</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Recordar que el método `Animate` posee sus propias  Funciones `Callback` , en este ejemplo doy un ejemplo de `complete` , también  se le puede pasar una función Anónima de la siguiente forma.

```
$('#cajita').animate({
     ...
},1000, function() { 
    /* End Animate */
    }
});
```

**Función Callback complete**

```js
$('#cajita').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({
     color: 'red',
      backgroundColor : '#fff'
  },{
  complete:  function() { 
  alert('final animación 1'); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#cajita{
  background:yellow;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<div id="cajita" >Click</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

El error lo tienes en:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat')!= "none")
```

Siempre será distinto de "none" ya que estas comparándolo con un objeto (la div con ese ID); te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
<div id="cont-campoBusq-relat" style="display:none">
```

además

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css("display")== "none") {
  // tu código
} else {
   // tu código
   $('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css("display","none");
}
```